# Expose a java method using JMX

Tags: java, jmx

We can expose a java method either through JMX  or as a Webservice. In which situation we use JMX for exposing a java function ? Is there any particular advantage the jmx have over webservice?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any particular advantage the jmx have over webservice?

JMX is pretty easy to enable and jconsole is a nice interface.   In addition, you are dealing completely with Java objects instead of having to interpret HTTP request and responses.

However, it really comes down to your usage and convenience.  If you already are exposing other web-services then I'd stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to consider:

1. Where is the consumer hosted?  If they are coming through the
   firewall to your servers, you are better off exposing your method as
   webservice.  If you expose it through JMX, you may have to rely on 
   jolokia to serve the requests over HTTP(S)
2. If the consumer(s) are written in languages other than java, I would prefer exposing the method as a webservice